# conf.int no longer working in 3.3 using ggplot2, stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2, summary, stat

I am using conf.int for the creation of boxes around a jitterplot. This had worked until upgrading R to 3.3. Is there a known fix for this?

```
stat_sum_df_all <- function(fun, geom="crossbar", ...) {
stat_summary(fun.data=fun, geom=geom, ...)
}


ggplot(dataset, aes(factor(Group), dataset[, y] )) + labs(y=y,     x="x") + 
    stat_sum_df_all("median_hilow",conf.int=1, linetype='solid')
```

Returns the following error:

Error: Unknown parameters: conf.int

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this issue by wrapping conf.int=1 with fun.args=(conf.int=1), as below:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(factor(Group), dataset[, y] )) + labs(y=y,     x="x") + 
stat_sum_df_all("median_hilow",fun.args=(conf.int=1), linetype='solid')
```